# How can I use NSURLConnection to make connection in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsthread

In one of my previous post someone suggest me to use the

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

To make connection in a new thread to keep GUI working without freezing during the connection.
But It now I can realize that this doesn't work.

This is the whole method.

```
- (void)postRequestWithURLState:(NSString *)url
{
    NSString *bodyRequest = nil;
    NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    //NSLog(@"-------------- bodyRequest: %@", bodyRequest);



    [theRequest setURL:requestURL];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:2.0];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[bodyRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [self.oauthAuthentication authorizeRequest:theRequest];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    self.web = conn;


}
```

That is part of a class called greader. So I use this method in this mode.

```
   reader = [[greader alloc] init];
   [reader setDelegate:self];
```

Than I call it [reader postRequestWithURLState:url].
But in this way it still freeze my app for some seconds. How can I execute this action without freezing my app for some seconds?

Comment: Are you doing something time consuming in any of the delegate methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange. I cannot see why this method would freeze your UI.

One simple solution is to call the method in separate thread. Make the reader a property (or pass it to the method below):

```
-(void)postReaderRequest:(NSURL)url {
   [self.reader postRequestWithURLState:url];
}
```

and then

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(postReaderRequest) 
   withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:url]];
```

If the result is the same, it must have been something else.

Comment: I'll try it... Anyway something else like what? What is the best way to do what I looking for?

Comment: `NSURLConnection` is the right way to go. Your UI freeze most likely comes from something else (code not posted).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSThread` to execute your `NSURLConnection`